# How to efficiently round only one column of numpy array to nearest 0.5?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

Is there an efficient way of rounding only one column of a numpy array? I.e. I want the numbers to round to nearest 0.5 which can be done with `round(number * 2.0) / 2.0`.

Assuming, I have the numpy array `tmp` and I aim at rounding the third column. There are the following things, I tried:

1. For just rounding to certain decimals, I could use

```py
tmp[:,2] = np.around(tmp[:,2],1)
```

But that's not what I want.

2. I define a function and try to apply along axis:

```py
def roundToHalf(number):
   return round(number * 2.0) / 2.0

tmp[:,2] = np.apply_along_axis(roundToHalf,0,tmp[:,2])
```

or

```py
tmp[:,2] = roundToHalf(tmp[:,2])
```

This doesn't work because I get an error:

```
*** TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

In the worst case, I would just go with a for loop. But I hope you guys can help me to find a smoother solution.

Comment: Instead of built-in `round` in `roundToHalf`, how about `np.around(number * 2.0) / 2.0`?

Comment: this worked for me `np.around(number * 2.0) / 2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote the function to handle a single number, not an array. You can use numpy's [around](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) to round an entire array. Your function would then be

```
import numpy as np
def roundToHalf(array):
   return np.around(array * 2.0) / 2.0
```

and if you input a numpy array it should work. Example below

```
In [24]: roundToHalf(np.asarray([3.6,3.8,3.3,3.1]))
Out[24]: array([3.5, 4. , 3.5, 3. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `np.vectorize()` on your function `roundToHalf()`, for it to be appliable on a numpy array

```py
roundToHalf_vect = np.vectorize(roundToHalf)
tmp[:,2] = roundToHalf_vect(tmp[:,2])
```